# Filter function creates empty rows

Tags: google-sheets

My understanding of the google sheets filter function is that it should limit the results to an array where the conditions are satisfied but I noticed this oddity:

[image]

Here is the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RL9cE6CYcpdNdkoKJvZc_KJ53d8QrNoMEQe-kH-4lo8/edit?usp=sharing

formula for result 1:
=filter(A2:A,A2:A<=105)

formula for result 2
=filter("x"&A2:A,A2:A<=105)

Question: Why does the 'x' continue down in rows where the condition is not satisfied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because empty cells treated as zero `0`. You can add an addition condition to `FILTER()` function to filter values greater than zero `0`.

```
=FILTER("x"&A2:A,A2:A<=105,A2:A>0)
```

[image]